# General linear group $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3}).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

General linear group $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ of $2\times2$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is defined as $$GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})=\{a,b:a^{3}=b^{2}=(ab)^{8}\}$$ where $a= 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 1 \\
   2 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ and $b= 
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ .

I needed the group $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ in form of elements power of $a$ and $b$ i.e. words in $a$ and $b.$ I tried like $\{e,a,a^{2},b,ab,ba,(ab)^{2},(ab)^{2}a,(ab)^{2}a^{2},(ab)^{3},(ab)^{3}a,(ab)^{3}a^{3},(ab)^{4},(ab)^{4}a,(ab)^{4}a^{2},(ab)^{5},(ab)^{5}a,(ab)^{5}a^{2},(ab)^{6},(ab)^{6}a,(ab)^{6}a^{2},(ab)^{7},(ab)^{7}a,(ab)^{7}a^{2}...\}$. But i don't know complete set in nice form. Please help me to form complete set in nice form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are only 81 matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z_3})$ and some will be singular so you could list the whole lot fairly easily.

Comment: Oops! That's a lot of work to do! $48$ elements to be computed.

Comment: there are $48$ elements..

Answer (score 1):

There are only $3^4 = 81$ possible elements, i.e., all matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are each $0, 1, $ or $2$. You need to eliminate those in which $ad - bc = 0$. And that'll give you a complete enumeration.

As for writing these as powers of $a$ and $b$, you know that they have the form 
$$
u_1 b u_2 b \ldots u_{n-1} b u_n
$$
where each $u_i$ is a power of $a$, i.e., they have the form "powers of $a$ interleaved with single $b$s".

Why? Because multiple $b$s can be simplified to $0$ or $1$ $b$, and multiple $a$s can be combined into a power.

You need only consider $u_i = e, a, a^2$, because $a^3 = 1$.

That makes for a not-too-long list.